# View a custom data type's values while debugging OCaml code

Tags: debugging, ocaml

I have a list called `list_ds` of a custom-defined data structure in my OCaml source. I compiled the source for debugging and ran the debugger halting execution of my code at a breakpoint. Now I want to check particular element of the data structure within the list. If I use the `print list_ds` command in the debugger, I see `[ abstr; abstr; abstr; abstr; <abstr>; ...]` - list with word `abstr`. If I use "print list_ds.(0)" command in the debugger, it tells me that `$1 : ds = abstr`. But I really want to see the elements of the `ds` data structure at the first location in the `list_ds`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to install your own custom print function for the type.  This is described in Section 16.8.8 of the [OCaml Debugger Manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual030.html).

A downside of this approach is that it requires quite a bit of setup, especially since the output must be done through the `Format` module.  You might be able to use the [deriving](http://code.google.com/p/deriving/) project to speed this up.  It can generate formatting functions automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas! I will have to spend some time to set the debugging environment i guess.